# Removing an item from ArrayList in a separate Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have a long running loop.

Inside the loop I have another loop to iterate (using iterator) on a arrayList.

If a condition is met while looping through array list I initiate a thread while passing it the current array list item and also the current iterator.

Some example code:

```
List<Test> testList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Test>());

//scanTests in a thread
while(scanTests) {
    for(Iterator<Test> itr = this.testList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        Test test = itr.next();
        if (test.closed == true && !test.inUpdateThread) {
            test.inUpdateThread = true;
            UpdateThread urt = new UpdateThread(test, itr);
            new Thread(urt).start();
        }
    }
}

//scanSomethingElse is in another thread
while (scanSomethingElse) {
    //manipulating testList 
}
```

If a condition is met in the *UpdateThread*, I want to remove the item from the *testList* like so:

```
this.itr.remove();
```

I have another long running loop (in another separate thread) concurrently and its doing similar types of processing on the array List (read, write etc...).

My question is if in this other loop I'm iterating the *testList* will this reflect the changes from the other loop?

(In case you're wondering why I'm using thread for sync, this is for remote resource and database interaction, and I need this loop to be constant and instantaneous without wait time).

Comment: I think if you remove elements while you are iterating, you will get a ConcurrentModificationException, See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: No. It is a common error. You can remove/add while iterating if you use add()/remove() method from the iterator. An iterator maintain a "modcount" (modification count) attribute which it updates at each operation. If you modify it.remove(), the modcount is incremented. If you list.remove(), the modcount is not incremented so that at the next it.next(), you get this exception. I think that the problem here is that the iterator itself is not thread safe

Comment: @adenoyelle if the item is removed by another thread it is surely NOT removed via iterator.remove() - so the Exception will occur

Comment: He is passing the iterator to the thread.

Comment: @lcplussplus : could you clarify what you do with the iterator in you UpdateThread? IMHO, looping on an iterator while passing it to another thread which can also update it is a serious design flaw.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the response. I'm only passing the current iterator to the thread for the purpose of removing the item from the testList listArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use something like:

```
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0;i < testList.size(); i++) {
        Test test = testList.get(i);
        if (test.closed == true && !test.inUpdateThread) {
            test.inUpdateThread = true;
            UpdateThread urt = new UpdateThread(some other constructor here);
            new Thread(urt).start();
        }; 

    };
};
```

//the UpdateThread class has a consructor UpdateThread(Test test, Iterator itr). so just modify it for fitting this example, or post it i think ki can do it for you.

Comment: so basically I would just call to remove testList.remove(test); in the UpdateThread instead of passing the iterator?

Comment: yes testList.remove(test); for example will remove test from the list.

Comment: I just want to remove that current "test" item while iterating, I can only determine if I want to remove it though in the UpdateThread.

Comment: so the UpdateThread constructor should be something like UpdateThread(Test test, List<Test> list) so you will be able to call list.remove(test) from within the UpdateThread class.

Comment: I was under the impression that using iterator for arrayList is the only way to remove the item while traversing it.

Comment: ok, for now I will accept your answer and confirm back until performed tests. thanks

Comment: just want to mention don't need to pass in the list to the constructor. I already have it set globally as property for main class.